# PHP won't include file - shows number instead?

Tags: php, module, include

I've run into a very strange problem with my PHP webapp. I've designed it to be modular, with my code divided into smaller files so it doesn't get too overwhelming. My app is a funds application management system for a nonprofit organization, and the module I'm having problems with calculates and outputs the number of business hours since an application's submission.

This "time" module is included in multiple different sections of my app. In some places, everything works fine. In one particular spot, however, the module doesn't seem to execute, and instead the number "12" is outputted. Could this be a result of my code doing too much at once, and causing PHP to run out of memory?

The "time" module:

```
<?php
/* Time Module
Added for Version: 1.1
Last Updated: 10/11/2012
*/

$timeSince = time() - (int)$item['timestamp']; //Calculate the number of seconds between now and the application's submission
$timeSince = $timeSince / 60 / 60; //60secs; 60mins - Convert the seconds to hours
$timeSince = round($timeSince); //Round up or down to give us a whole number

if( //Set the highlight color to green if we're within the review timeframe.
($timeSince <= 12 && $item['appStatus']=="0") ||
($timeSince <= 48 && $item['appStatus']=="1") ||
($timeSince <= 72 && $item['appStatus']=="2")
)
    $timeColor="#090";
elseif( //If we're slightly behind the timeframe, highlight as yellow
($timeSince <= 24 && $item['appStatus']=="0") ||
($timeSince <= 60 && $item['appStatus']=="1") ||
($timeSince <= 84 && $item['appStatus']=="2")
)
    $timeColor="#F90";
else //If we're far behind the timeframe, highlight as red
    $timeColor="#F33";
?>
Submitted: <?php echo date("F j, Y", $item['timestamp']) ?><br>

<?php if($item['appStatus']=="0" || $item['appStatus']=="1" || $item['appStatus']=="2") { ?>
<span style="color:<?php echo $timeColor ?>"><?php echo $timeSince ?></span> Hours Since Submission
<?php } ?>
```

Code where the file is included (under a row of action buttons):

```
<div style="float:right; padding:10px; text-align:right;">
<?php if(isset($includePrefix)) { ?>
    <a href="appAssets/print.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" target="_blank">
    <img src="appAssets/print.png" alt="Print This Application" align="middle" title="Print This Application" /></a>&nbsp;

    <a href="mailto:<?php echo $item['agencyEmail'] ?>">
    <img src="appAssets/email.png" alt="Email Agency" align="middle" title="Email Agency" /></a>

    <?php if(!$hide) { ?>
        <a href="#" id="disbursementLink">
        <img src="appAssets/dollar.png" alt="Disbursment Instructions" align="middle" title="Disbursement Instructions" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <br />
<?php } ?>

<?php include_once("time.php") ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaand no code. Please show us what you've tried first.

Comment: giving the vast amounts of example code you've provided, I'm going to blame it on solar flares sending a stellar photon through your cpu and burning out the transistor that was handling the include.

Comment: My "time" module code is from an older version. It simply calculates the raw hours between the two timestamps. I've created a function that calculates the business hours.

Answer (score 0):

PHP running out of memory yields a very specific "Out of memory" fatal error. I doubt your scripts are doing something that would make PHP run out of memory because you are not processing anything memory intensive (no image/video processing, no large sets of SQL data being loaded).

Since you're not seeing the error, just an odd output (12) I'll assume you don't have your error reporting activated:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or other level if it's more convenient
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); // outputs errors to the browser
ini_set('scream.enabled', TRUE); // ignores the `@` error silencing operator
```

If there is no error (ignoring notices & warnings) then most likely your code is working. The problem becomes reconciling the way the code was written with the way it was intended to work.

In a `procedural programming` approach the variables you're using are global. The environment does not unset those variables when exiting procedure scope (after the closing braces) or when exiting the module scope (after the end of one file).

An environment like this can allow a global variable to be set at some point and another section of the code can try to use it later on - expecting it to have a different value. Or even more likely - when calling a module multiple times its variables continue having the values they had at the point of last execution.

Answer (score 0):

When I turned on error reporting, I found that for some reason, it was including another file called "time.php" which was in the root of the site. This particular file was a test script I was working on, where I was trying to calculate the business hours between two dates (I can share it if anyone's interested). This file was outputting the number "12," because that was the time between the test dates I was working with.

My webapp is comprised of a web of includes that spans multiple directory levels, so PHP must have rules it follows in this situation. The original script execution starts in the root of the site, so it must look there for a file before it looks in a subdirectory (the "time" module is included from another module, which is located in the "modules" subdirectory). Since there was a "time.php" in the root of the site, and a "time.php" in the modules directory, it was favoring the one in the site root.